# What's the difference between WC() and $woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I want to unset some WooCommerce session variables because on page load the hooks I'm using haven't fired which leaves previous session data populating the checkout shipping table.

Within any functions accessed from the hook callbacks, I can access WooCommerce session vars like:

`WC()->session->get('foo');`

However, when outside of those callbacks, `WC` is undefined. I tried setting:

`global $woocommerce;` and accessing via `$woocommerce->session->__unset('foo');` but got the notice:

> Trying to get property of non-object

and the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function __unset() on null

So, clearly this `$woocommerce` global is not the same as `WC` (which I guess is exposed by the hooks?)

I think I can unset these variables using one of the first hooks that will fire on the checkout page, but it got me wondering:

What is the difference between `WC()` and `$woocommerce`? Aren't they both ways to access WooCommerce methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wc();` returns the singleton instance of `WooCommerce` to prevent the need to use globals.

WC sets the `$woocommerce` global this way: `$GLOBALS['woocommerce'] = wc();`, so using one or the other seems the same...

**EDIT**

About your errors, you got them because `$woocommerce->session` has not been set. WC initializes `WC_Session_Handler` only on frontend or CRON requests. Choose your action hook accordingly.

Comment: So were my errors caused by a syntax mistake? What's the right way to call the `__unset()` function on a session variable using the `$woocommerce` global?

Comment: @armadadrive, see my edit.

Comment: This is awesome. One less step away from globals!