# WooCommerce get physical store address

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes

In WooCommerce admin settings (/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings) there are several fields to set the store address (street, city, country).

How can one retrieve this in a theme's templates? I wouldn't want to hardcode such informations into the theme.

Comment: store address? are you talking about getting shop url?

Comment: No sorry, I meant the physical store address. Street, city, country.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The physical address of the store (and many other settings) are stored in WP's options table (wp_options where "wp_" is the table prefix being used on the site).

The option names are:

- woocommerce_store_address
- woocommerce_store_address_2
- woocommerce_store_city
- woocommerce_store_postcode
- woocommerce_default_country

The tricky thing is the woocommerce_default_country value.  That stores the country AND state/province info depending on your selection in the "Country/State" dropdown selector in the settings.  If it's just a country, it will be the country code, but if it's country "plus" something, it will be separated by a colon ":" (such as "US:IL").

So the following is a generic way of doing a US address. Other countries/provinces may vary slightly depending on (1) what's in the woocommerce_default_country value (which may be just a country alone) and (2) how you want to output the info.

```
// The main address pieces:
$store_address     = get_option( 'woocommerce_store_address' );
$store_address_2   = get_option( 'woocommerce_store_address_2' );
$store_city        = get_option( 'woocommerce_store_city' );
$store_postcode    = get_option( 'woocommerce_store_postcode' );

// The country/state
$store_raw_country = get_option( 'woocommerce_default_country' );

// Split the country/state
$split_country = explode( ":", $store_raw_country );

// Country and state separated:
$store_country = $split_country[0];
$store_state   = $split_country[1];

echo $store_address . "<br />";
echo ( $store_address_2 ) ? $store_address_2 . "<br />" : '';
echo $store_city . ', ' . $store_state . ' ' . $store_postcode . "<br />";
echo $store_country;
```

This certainly could be condensed quite a bit and made neater, but I was verbose in the code for clarity.

Also, depending on the store location, etc, you may or may not want to include the country/state info at all, or you may want to alter what it output based on the saved value.  For example, in the case of US addresses, the country is "US", not "USA", and the state info is the abbreviated mail code (i.e. "IL" for Illinois).  So the actual value and how you intend to use it will determine what you want to do with it for output. (Hope that makes sense.)

Comment: The field name is `woocommerce_store_address_2`, with understore before '2'.

Comment: whoops - not sure how I messed that one up. I've edited above accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of the `get_option()` method mentioned above, it's much better to use the built-in functions via the main instance of WooCommerce `WC()`, thereby accessing the methods of the [`WC_Countries`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Countries.html) class:

```
WC()->countries->get_base_address();
WC()->countries->get_base_address_2();
WC()->countries->get_base_city();
WC()->countries->get_base_postcode();
WC()->countries->get_base_state();
WC()->countries->get_base_country();
```

For one, the place where the information is stored could change, but the method to get it stays the same. And secondly, in case a plugin changes the value using filters. Looking at the [source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#168-177) the latter gets obvious:

```
public function get_base_address() {
    $base_address = get_option( 'woocommerce_store_address', '' );
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_countries_base_address', $base_address );
}
```

Additional information:

- [What's the difference between `WC()` and `$woocommerce`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/275905/22534)
- [Classes in WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/class-reference/)

Comment: The state is selected from woocommerce with the same dropdown that says `Country / Region`Is this "Region" stored separately and can be accessed through `get_base_state()`?

Answer (score 1):

To get the shop country full name  :

```
WC()->countries->countries[WC()->countries->get_base_country()];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a specific function in WooCommerce to return shop (or other) URLs (at least that I know of).  But there is a function `wc_get_page_id()` that will get the page ID by name, and the ID can be used in WP's `get_permalink()` function to return the URL.

Here are some examples:

Shop page URL:

`echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );`

Cart page URL:

`echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) );`

Checkout page URL:

`echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) );`

My Account page URL:

`echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually looking to retrieve the physical addresse (like street etc)

Comment: Ahhhh... sorry - I was thinking URL address. I'll leave this answer in case anyone later needs this (if it comes up in someone's search for URL address), but will post another answer for physical address which is stored in the options table.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will return the store location in the same format as that used in WooCommerce for shipping addresses. (This is useful for example if you are building a shipping method calculator and you need to do address processing.)

```
function get_store_location() {
    $countries = WC()->countries;
    $location = [];

    foreach ( [ 'country', 'state', 'postcode', 'city', 'address', 'address_2' ] as $field ) {
        $location[ $field ] = $countries->{"get_base_$field"}();
    }

    return $location;
}
```